# ActionBarSherlock: How to bypass the Holo Theme for 4.x devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I am trying to bypass the Holo theme for 4.x devices (such that the app looks the same on all versions 2.x to 4.x). I have tried this by changing the theme.xml from values-14/ folder with the ones from values/ but the action bar disappears. Has anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other themes are not [required](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html) to be available on devices since Holo was introduced. Which means: you will run into devices in the future that only have Holo.

If you only want your app to look the same everywhere you could make use of [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) which ports the Holo theme to older devices.

HoloEverywhere works great with ActionBarSherlock.